# Can't get bower install polymer 'bower-components' folder is missing?

Tags: javascript, gulp, polymer, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install bower and polymer as part of a project for Udacity
I am provided with a repo to clone and install bower and gulp within it
At the end of the installation, I get Error 'Polymer is not defined'

Here is the list of commands I used:

1. `git clone https://github.com/udacity/exoplanet-explorer.git`
2. `cd exoplanet-explorer`
3. `npm install -g gulp bower`
4. `npm install && bower install -f polymer-starter-kit`
5. `gulp serve`

Here is my bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "polymer-starter-kit",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.1.0",
    "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.0",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.1",
    "platinum-elements": "PolymerElements/platinum-elements#^1.1.0",
    "neon-elements": "PolymerElements/neon-elements#^1.0.0",
    "page": "visionmedia/page.js#~1.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "*",
    "test-fixture": "PolymerElements/test-fixture#^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have a screenshot for every single command I used and how my project folder looks like
If anyone is interested to help please contact me, I would appreciate any help https://www.facebook.com/andrew.rsb !!
Here is a link for the problem I uploaded on Udacity if anyone has access to it:https://knowledge.udacity.com/questions/46863
I have been stuck for 4 days and I have nothing else to try!!

Comment: Polymer 1 is old and relies on a number of deprecated/removed web APIs. I would recommend trying Polymer 3. It no longer uses bower.

Comment: it gives me an error: failed to connect to port 443,
what do you suggest, can you contact me privately if you are experienced with this !! i am really stuck